# ImageView disappear after changed orientation

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, orientation

I have just started in developing in Android. So far I am learning stuff. I am stuck with this problem. In my onCreate method, i have a button to select an image in the device and the onActivityResult to get the image and display the image in an ImageView

After researching and looking for answers in the internet, someone advice that I am missing the onSaveInstanceState. so I created it.  Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("BitmapImage", bitmap);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    image = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("BitmapImage");
    targetImage.setImageBitmap(image);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri targetUri = data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(targetUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                this.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
                targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

After building and running the code, selecting image and displaying it in ImageView works fine. When i change the orientation, image selected is still displayed. However when i rotate back again, the image displayed is gone.
Where am i doing wrong. Any advice and help is appreciated.

Comment: Check if saveinstancestate is null in onCreate and try restoring in onCreate if its not null, you can add logs and check why it is not getting restored, make sure you are saving it correctly.

Comment: It does return null.. then @RobVoisey suggested to change my Bitmap to this.bitmap = BitmapFactory. It solved the issue.. but when i rotate back again to portrait, the issue then occurs again.

Comment: please check below link and use Picasso, this problem is done.  http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you storing 'bitmap' correctly? Here you are storing it to a local variable:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And here you are using a field:

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

Looks like the field isn't being set so the `onSaveInstanceState` is storing a null value. Try removing `Bitmap bitmap;` or change `bitmap = BitmapFactory...` to `this.bitmap = BitmapFactory`.

EDIT:

Also try storing bitmap here:

```
image = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("BitmapImage");
targetImage.setImageBitmap(image);
```

By changing it to:

```
image = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("BitmapImage");
this.bitmap = image;
targetImage.setImageBitmap(this.bitmap);
```

I'm not sure what image is though as you haven't include the delcaration in the post.

Comment: this.bitmap = BitmapFactory worked like a charm. thank you very much.. however when i rotate back again to portrait, the same issue occurs.

Comment: can you update the question with the code you changed it to?

Comment: I have updated the question and changed the bitmap = BitmapFactory.. to this.bitmap = BitmapFactory...

Comment: Check my edit; what is 'image'? You are storing it but never doing anything with it. I would guess that 'bitmap' is being cleared after the orientation change and never set again.

Comment: you are a genius. It did solved my problem. bitmap was never stored in image that is why it is never getting the value. image by the way is a Bitmap.